# Spliting nested date lists in DF columns and calculate AVG hour

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Lets say i have this DF

| ID | date_time |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-03-13 21:10:56, 2020-06-02 22:18:06, 2020-04-14 22:10:56, 2021-06-02 22:18:06 |
| 2 | 2010-09-13 21:43:09, 2011-05-04 23:08:15,2012-06-04 23:08:16 |
| 3 | 2013-06-14 23:29:17, 2014-08-13 23:20:22,2014-08-13 23:20:22 |

I want to remove YYYYMMDD string at the first position after every single comma and calculate AVG hour from list

Final output would be:

| ID | date_time | AVG_hour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 21:10:56,22:18:06,22:10:56 | 22 |
| 2 | 21:43:09,23:08:15,23:08:16 | 22 |
| 3 | 23:29:17,23:20:22,23:20:22 | 22 |

I tried following; but it did not work:

```py
df['date_time'] = [para.split(None, 1)[1] for para in df['date_time']]
df.head()
```

Comment: Why is average hour for `ID=3` `22` ? Do you mean compute the average from all hours in all lists and assign it to the `AVG_hour` ?

Comment: Yes, just like Naveeds answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way to do it

```
# Split on comma, convert each value to date time and then to time delta
# take the total seconds and convert to hours
# np.mean to take average and then round the result

df['Avg_hour']=df['date_time'].str.split(',').apply(lambda x: round(np.mean([ pd.to_timedelta((pd.to_datetime(i)).strftime('%H:%M:%S')).total_seconds()/3600 for i in x])))
df
```

```
    ID  date_time                                           Avg_hour
0   1   2020-03-13 21:10:56, 2020-06-02 22:18:06, 2020...   22
1   2   2010-09-13 21:43:09, 2011-05-04 23:08:15,2012-...   23
2   3   2013-06-14 23:29:17, 2014-08-13 23:20:22,2014-...   23
```

```
#same as above, round to 2 decimal places

df['Avg_hour']=df['date_time'].str.split(',').apply(lambda x: round(np.mean([ pd.to_timedelta((pd.to_datetime(i)).strftime('%H:%M:%S')).total_seconds()/3600 for i in x]), 2))
df
```

```
    ID  date_time                                           Avg_hour
0   1   2020-03-13 21:10:56, 2020-06-02 22:18:06, 2020...   21.99
1   2   2010-09-13 21:43:09, 2011-05-04 23:08:15,2012-...   22.66
2   3   2013-06-14 23:29:17, 2014-08-13 23:20:22,2014-...   23.39
```